# Conceptual question about assuming the existence of a function in order to prove the existence of another function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

I would like to raise a question using an exercise from Tao's *Analysis I* as an example. The exercise is presented as follows:

> Let $f:\mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ be a function, and let $c$ be a natural number. Show that there exists a function $a : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that $$a(0) =c $$
>   and
>   $$a(n++)=f(n,a(n)) \text{ for all } n \in \mathbb N$$

My question is **not about** how to solve this problem. Rather, I am trying to understand what exactly the assumption "$f: \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$" is trying to suggest to the reader.

I have just learned quite a bit more detail about functions (e.g. the difference between *set functions* and *class functions*). In light of this, in the absence of providing a specific *mapping rule*, it seems to me that "$f: \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$" must be some sort of **shorthand** for:

> "*$f$ is a set function... where the exact mapping rule is arbitrary...but we at least know the sets from which the first and second component of the ordered pairs come from*".

Is this a correct interpretation?

If so, then is this a correct abridged formalization of the overall proof?

$\forall f \text{ such that } (\forall (x,y) \in f, x \in \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \land y \in \mathbb N)$, $\exists a \text{ such that ...}$

Comment: I believe $a(n++)$ is $a(n+1)$...

Comment: @JeanMarie Sure. That is the notation that Tao uses for successors. I'm not sure if that is pertinent to my question, but nonetheless, yes, you are correct.

Comment: Yes, your interpretation and the follow up are correct.

Comment: I think you are leaving too much out to the point of making the question so vague that it is not very useful. The exercise is showing you how to formalize definitions by recursion.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo yes, I am aware of what the exercise is for. My question is not about the exercise. I'm just using this exercise because it is the most recent example I have seen where a function is assumed to exist in order to make an argument. I wanted to give a concrete example of where I see these styles of proofs. I can edit the question if you would like.

Comment: You are asking what the general idea "of these sorts of problems" is. It is not something as what you are saying. The point is that these vagueries are not very useful in practice, where we deal with all sorts of (set and class) functions all the time.

Comment: (So, yes, clarifying what you are actually asking might help. But the vaguer and more general you make it, the more likely it will end up being unanswerable or not particularly enlightening.)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo hmmm. I think, maybe, there may be a misunderstanding of intent. I just wanted to make sure I understood how one should interpret the notation of a "function without a mapping rule" in the antecedent of an implication. Mark Kamsma has provided me with this answer. However, a certainly more interesting question, which I think may be "less vague", is how does one formally pose this style of proof using quantifiers? I can see how to formally express the consequent of the implication...but I do not understand how to express the antecedent.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo "For all vaguely defined functions, there exists a specific unique function" ?

Comment: The less you use expressions like "vaguely defined", the better. It would be natural to understand "vaguely defined function" as meaning something different from "function" (and there are contexts where it does), but, the way you are using the term, it means the same.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo oh, I did not realize that at all. By "vaguely defined", I wanted to convey that the function $f: \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ has no mapping rule and therefore cannot be viewed as a set function (because it doesn't contain...or specify... explicit ordered pairs that would otherwise belong to it).

Comment: It is a set function. It is not vaguely defined. It does not matter whether you have a "mapping rule" telling you how to compute its values.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo hmmm. This sort of contradicts my entire mental model for what I thought a set function was. Now I have no clue what's going on hah.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I included an edit. Is this the correct way of thinking about this problem?

Comment: Again, in your question you talk of "sufficiently vague properties". This does not help you in any way and it does not really mean anything. It is noise, it distracts. Maybe you just want to say that the function is arbitrary. Ok. Then say that it is arbitrary. even better is to not say it. It is understood that unless you give me more information about a function, it is arbitrary.

Comment: Once you clarify all of this, it is still far from clear what you mean by "these sorts of problems". Which sorts? All you did was to provide *one* very specific problem. How are we to extrapolate from it?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I'm not really sure what you are looking for. There is clearly a language barrier (in the sense that my every day english is clashing with mathematical terminology that you are privy to and I am not). I think I made the necessary edits, but I don't really know what you are asking me to do. By "these sorts of problems", I would have thought that it is fairly generalizable, as I have encountered several exercises posed as "Let some arbitrary function exist. Show that this other function must therefore exist".

Comment: How is defined $n++$? Is it the successor of the successor of $n$?

Comment: @RayLittleRock yes.

Comment: @S.Cramer I am certainly not as qualified as a professional mathematician, but I think I know what you mean since I have struggled with similar problems before. As with the earlier commenter, yes, you are correct. Your FOL statement captures the fact that $f$ is an arbitrary function. Note that a mapping rule is NOT a prerequisite for defining a function; it is simply a set of ordered pairs. In this sense, saying an "arbitrary natural number" is equivalent to saying "an arbitrary function" equivalent again to "an arbitrary set of ordered pairs" (where some properties hold)

Comment: @masiewpao thank you!

Comment: @S. Cramer. - The problem may come from the fact that the sentence you have formalized at the end is not the consequent, but is by itself the whole conditional. "For all $f$ such that" is a shorthand for " for all $f$, if $f$ is a an operation on N ...then... ". The consequent is the existential part of the statement. This existential statement  is your only goal ( under the taken as admitted hypothesis) " $f$ is an operation on N and $c$ is a natural number".

Comment: @RayLittleRock thank you for that last little insight. I'll actually be writing a question about exactly that as a follow up to this question. Cheers~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wording of this statement can be clarified by inserting the implied quantifiers:

> For all functions $f : \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ and for all natural numbers $c$ there exists a function $a : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that...

This is exactly analogous to other statements in mathematics which I'm sure you're comfortable with, for example this kind of statement which occurs all the time in the definition of a limit:

> For all $\epsilon > 0$ and for all $x \in \mathbb R$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that ...

With the quantifiers as expressed, once you specify the variable names, and the sets in which those variables are allowed to take their values, there is utterly no difference between the logical meaning of these two statements:

- In the second statement, $\epsilon$ varies over the set $(0,\infty)$; $x$ varies over the set $\mathbb R$; and $\delta$ varies over the set $(0,\infty)$.
- In the first statement: $f$ varies over the set of functions with domain $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ and range $\mathbb N$; $c$ varies over the set $\mathbb N$; and $a$ varies over the set of functions with domain $\mathbb N$ and range $\mathbb N$.

Comment: is it safe to say that when exercises are structured as "Let blah blah blah...Show that bleh bleh bleh...", we are almost always dealing with the formalization that you just described? i.e. "Let blah blah..." will be formalized to a "$\forall$ statement" and the "Show that bleh bleh..." will be formalized to a "$\exists$ statement"?

Comment: It's hard to say whether that is *almost always* true; it's quite common, but not universal. I would say that it's something that you have to learn by context, as you learn to read math-ese.

Answer (score 0):

A comment on the logical aspect of the question.

You seem to see things like this : we want to prove the existence of function $a$ , and , to do this, we make a "risky assumption" as to the existence of a function $f$ such that...

Here the existence of function $f$ is not a conjecture, it is simply the hypothesis of the problem. You are supposed to put yourself in the situation where such an arbitrary function $f$ exists ( satisfying the conditions given) , and , under this hypothesis, to prove the existence of at least one function satisfying the conditions for $a$.

Although rigorously the proof amounts to proving a universally quantified conditional, your proof will be finished as soon as you have reached the existential statement ( under your initial hypothesis of course).

---

The complete goal is :

$\forall (f)(c)$

IF ($f$ is a binary  operation on $\mathbb N$ & $c\in \mathbb N$)

THEN ( $\exists (a)$ such that $a$ is a function from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$ & $a$ satisfies the following properties : .... ).

As you see, ***the goal is not to prove the existence of $a$, period***. The goal is to prove the existence of $a$, ***in case***  we have a function $f$ having the required properties.

The " IF part" is the hypothesis.

Any arbitrary function $f$ will do ( as soon as you do not make any extra assuption as to $f$, beyond the fact that it is an operation on the set of natural numbers). In the same way, any arbitrary number $c$ will do.

The arbitrariness of $f$ and of $c$ is what will allow you, in the end, to generalize and to say that what you have proved holds " for all $f$ and for all $c$".

---

Let me take a stupid example to make things clear.

You are asked to prove that :

" For all person A and B, if (A IS 0.5 m. tall  AND B 50 times as tall as A) then ( there is a person that is taller than any elephant )."

We do *not* assume anything *in order to* prove *the actual existence* of a person that is taller than any elephant.

We simply say that : *in case* it happened that there were a person A being 0.5m tall and a 50 times as tall person B ( whoever A and B may be) , *in that hypothetical case*, B would be 25 m tall, which would imply ( hypothetically) that there is an $x$ such that $x$ is a person, and $x$ is taller than any elephant.

A proof would go like this:

"Let's admit that A and B are persons , that A is 0,5m talland B is 50 tims as tall as A. ( That is, you would assume the antecedent of the conditional).

What would follow from this?"

Then, you'd try to reach the consequent , under your assumption.

Comment: I'm not sure that this answers the core question from OP

Comment: True the question has 2 aspects: (1) a definitional aspect ( what is a binary operation on a set S) (2) a logical aspect ( what is the logical status of the assumption). I aimed at explaining what are the givens of the questions. From my point of view, once these givens are identified *as such* ( that is not as " risky assumlptions" but simply as *hypotheses*) the logical issue disappears and the OP can concentrate on the *goal*.

Comment: @masiewpao. - Answer edited  in order to take your comment into account.

Comment: I think this still misses the core question. The OP doesn't seem confused about the definition of an operation, and they also specified they were not looking for a solution to the exercise they quoted. My understanding is they want to know how to formalise in FOL what an arbitrary function is. Also from their comments their logical issue was not with understanding how logical implication works; they want to know how to formalise the expression of the antecedent.

Comment: @masiewpao.- The title and the way  the goal is formalized at the end show that the conditional form of this goal is not well understood. The OP is prevented from answering by the misleading idea that the goal is to prove the existence of function $a$, " period" ( I mean , categorically) while the real goal is to prove the conditional existence of a function $a$, in the hypothetical case where  there is some function $f$f satisfying such and such conditions...).

Comment: Perhaps I have misinterpreted what the OP was unsure about, but to me it seemed as if he was asking whether his formalisation was correct, and indeed it was. I don't quite see where it seems that OP has failed to understand what the hypothesis is. The example statement is of the form $\forall f \in S_f \exists a \in S_a P(f,a)$, where $S_f$ is the set of all functions with the specified conditions for $f$ (and similarly for $a$). I think the OP got exactly right

Comment: @RayLittleRock thank you for putting the effort that you did in this response. It led me to ask a follow up question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3586267/forall-x-s-t-phix-exists-y-s-t-phix-y-versus-forall-x-bi?noredirect=1#comment7373227_3586267, which led to an even better conceptual understanding. Cheers~

Comment: S.Cramer.- You're welcome. The new question you've asked is actually a useful one, just upvoted this question.