# "$\forall x$ s.t. $\phi(x), \exists y$ s.t $\phi'(x,y)$" versus "$\forall x, \big( \phi(x)\implies \exists y $ s.t $\phi'(x,y)\big)$"

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am trying to gain some insight into how one **understands** proofs that can be generically described as fitting this mold:

> Let $x$ be some object that has a specific list of properties. Show that some other object $y$ exists with a specific property that relates to $x$.

(An example of such a proof that follows this form can be found here: [Proof of a proposition about recursion definition (Terence Tao's Analysis I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778816/proof-of-a-proposition-about-recursion-definition-terence-taos-analysis-i)).

To tackle such a proof, I would do the following:

Firstly, I would note that this statement can be formally restated as:

$$\forall x \text{ such that } \phi(x), \exists y \text { such that } \phi'(x,y)$$

Then, I would pick an arbitrary element $x^*$ that satisfies $\phi(x^*)$. From this, I would try to construct a corresponding $y^*$ that satisfies $\phi'(x^*,y^*)$.

Because $x^*$ was arbitrary, I have thus proven that "$\forall x \text{ such that } \phi(x), \exists y \text { such that } \phi'(x,y)$" is a true statement.

I believe this is the standard strategy.

---

I have always wondered how (and if) the aforementioned strategy can be reformulated using implications. An author of an "Answer Post" from a question posed here ([Conceptual question about assuming the existence of a function in order to prove the existence of another function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3585834/conceptual-question-about-assuming-the-existence-of-a-function-in-order-to-prove)) made the following (paraphrased) comment:

> The "such that $\phi(x)$" statement can actually be reformulated as an antecedent of an implication. Additionally, the "$\exists y \text{ such that } \phi'(x,y)$" can be reformulated as the consequent of the same implication. Therefore, "$\forall x \text{ such that } \phi(x), \exists y \text { such that } \phi'(x,y)$" is actually logically equivalent to "$\forall x, \big( \phi(x)\implies \exists y \text { such that } \phi'(x,y)\big) $."

**Could some please elaborate on this a little more?**

Edit: The proper format may actually be "$\forall x, \exists y \big( \phi(x)\implies \phi'(x,y)\big) $"

(however I am not sure)

Comment: Do *not* write "such that" in the middle of a symbolic statement.  It may be pronounced, but it is not written.  You might use a period, comma, or colon to punctuate, or just leave a spacing.

Comment: @GrahamKemp thanks for the input. Also, do you agree with the validity of the symbolic statement in the edit: "$\forall x, \exists y \big( \phi(x)\implies \phi'(x,y)\big) $"

Comment: I agree that it is a *proper translation* of the English sentence.

Comment: @GrahamKemp haha, I'm trying to determine the nuance in your response. I take it as you, personally, would use the symbolic statement: $\forall x \big ( \phi(x) \rightarrow \exists y,\phi'(x,y)\big)$ instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exact same strategy works for the reformulated statement, since they're equivalent.  If you want to prove $$\forall x(\phi(x)\implies \exists y,\phi'(xy))$$  what do you do?  Pick an arbitrary $x$ such that $\phi(x)$ holds and then try to find a $y$ such that $\phi'(x,y)$ holds, or show that the non-existence of such a $y$ would lead to a contradiction.

If you try to state them in words, both statements mean something like, "Any time we have an $x$ such that $\phi(x)$ holds, there is a $y$ such that $\phi'(x,y)$ holds."

Formally, the second alternative you give $$\forall x, \exists y \big( \phi(x)\implies \phi'(x,y)\big)$$ means the same thing, but it seems a little unnatural to me.  However, I'm by no means a logician.

Comment: The double arrow is depreciated for use as a connective in favour of the single arrow.  Secondly, *always* use brackets to clarify operational precedence.  $~\bigl(\forall x~,\phi(x)\bigr)\to\exists y~,\phi'(x,y)$ is an entirely different statement from $\forall x~,\bigl(\phi(x)\to\exists y~,\phi'(x,y)\bigr)~$.  When there is doubt, parenthesis it out.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thanks, I see what you mean.  Corrected (I hope).

Comment: @GrahamKemp i'm still quite the novice...so I just wanted to confirm that the reason the two symbolic statements you stated are different is because IN THE FIRST ONE, (i.e. $\big(\forall x, \phi(x)\big) \rightarrow \exists y,\phi'(x,y)$ ) the $x$ in the consequent is actually functioning as a free variable, correct?

Comment: Yes; *that* among other things too.  The universal statement is also the antecedent of a conditional in the first, rather than the conditional statement being quantified inside the scope of a universal in the second.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer : mathematical symbolism sometimes conceals conditional form in the same manner as natural language does ; in a proof, the proper conditional form of the goal has to be recovered in order to adopt the right  strategy ( consistng in assuming the antecedent , in order to derive the consequent, under the initial assumption).

---

- The question is a grammatical one, and amounts to asking how to formalize sentences such as :

[ Every X + relative clause] + Verb + Attribute / Object.

[ An X + adjective} + Verb + Attribute/ Object.

[ An X + participle clause] + Verb + Object/ Attribute

All these grammatical forms are abbreviating devices used by natural language; logic teaches us that the  logical structure ( beyond the surface grammar form) involves a conditional.

- The point is that, mathematics also uses this abbreviating device. Sometimes, a change in typography ( with the use of ***indices***) accompanies this sort of writing.

For example, in order to say ( note the relative clauses below) :

For all $\epsilon$ ***that is strictly greater than 0***, there is a $\delta$ ***that is strictly greater than 0,*** such that if ($0 < | x-a| < \delta$) then ($ | f(x)-L| < \epsilon$)

one will write

$\forall\epsilon_{(>0)}\exists \delta_{(>0)} [(0 < | x-a| < \delta)\rightarrow ( | f(x)-L| < \epsilon)]$.

But this is an abbreviation, and in fact, it " hides" a conditional form: for all $\epsilon$ , ***if $\epsilon$ is strictly greater than 0***, then, there exists some $\delta$ such that, if.... then... .

- So how to formalize?

[ Every X + relative clause] + Verb + Attribute / Object.

***Every natural number that is different from 0 is the successor of some natural number.***

$\forall (x) {[ (x\in\mathbb N) \wedge (x\neq0)] \rightarrow [\exists (y) (y\in\mathbb N) \wedge (x=S(y)]}$

or

$\forall (x)_{ (x\in\mathbb N)} [ (x\neq0) \rightarrow (\exists (y) (y\in\mathbb N) \wedge (x=S(y)) ] $

[ An X + adjective} + Verb + Attribute/ Object.

***Every even integer  has an even square.***

$\forall(x) [( x \in \mathbb Z \wedge x/2\in\mathbb Z) \rightarrow ( x^2 / 2 \in \mathbb Z)] $

[ An X + participle clause  ] + Verb + Object/ Attribute

***All sets having no element are identical ( with |A| = cardinal of set A)*** :

$\forall (S)(T) [ (|S|=0 \wedge |T| = 0 ) \rightarrow ( S=T)$]

Note : there are certainly some parenthesis mistakes I haven't corrected.

Comment: lovely! Very informative. I have a follow up question that I plan on asking shortly. Cheers~